# React Router Dom & Firebase Auth: history.push changes url but does not render new component when called after firebase auth create account

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, react-router-dom

**What I am trying to do**
I'm using Firebase v9 and React-router-dom v5.3.0 to make a sign up form which creates a new account and redirects the user to the home screen when an account is created. The route for the home screen is "/".

**The problem**
My plan is to call `history.push("/")` after calling the sign up function, which should take me to the home screen. However, when running the code, `history.push("/")` only updated the URL and did not redirect me to the home screen. I had to reload the page for the home screen to show up, otherwise I'd just be stuck in the sign up form. I have been fiddling with the code and what surprises me is when I remove `await signup(email, password)`, history.push works just as intended. I suspect this behavior has something to do with firebase's sign up function, but I don't know what it is. Can someone offer an explanation?

**The code**
Here's my code for the sign up form:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { useAuth } from "../contexts/AuthContext";

function Signup() {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
    const [cfPassword, setCfPassword] = useState("");
    const {signup} = useAuth();
    const history = useHistory();

    async function handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (password !== cfPassword) {
            console.log("Passwords do not match!");
            return;
        }
        try {
            await signup(email, password);
            history.push("/"); // Problematic code is here. This works fine when I remove the previous line.
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.message);
        }
    }
    
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Create an account</h1>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <input type="email" value={email} onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} placeholder="Email"/>
                <input type="password" value={password} onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)} placeholder="Password"/>
                <input type="password" value={cfPassword} onChange={(e) => setCfPassword(e.target.value)} placeholder="Confirm Password"/>
                <input type="submit" value="Sign up"/>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Signup;
```

The code containing the authentication context and the related function for signing up:

```
import { auth } from "../firebase";
import { useState, useEffect, useContext, createContext } from "react";
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";

const AuthContext = createContext();

export function useAuth() {
    return useContext(AuthContext);
}

export function AuthProvider({children}) {
    const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState();
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

    function signup(email, password) {
        return createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
    }

    const value = {
        currentUser,
        signup
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscriber = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
            setIsLoading(true);
            setCurrentUser(user);
            setIsLoading(false);
        });
        return unsubscriber;
    }, []);

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
            {!isLoading && children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

My `App.jsx` component containing the router.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { AuthProvider } from './contexts/AuthContext';
import Home from './pages/mains/home/Home';
import Signup from './components/Signup';

function App() {
    return (
        <AuthProvider>
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
                    <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        </AuthProvider>
    )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Can you update your question to include all relevant code? What, or where, is rendering this `Signup` component? Where is `Signupu` rendered relative to your app's router? Are you rendering more than one router component in your app? Does `history.push` work elsewhere? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @DrewReese I just updated the question. Hopefully it's clearer now. :)

Comment: Is `signup` or `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` throwing an error or rejected Promise? Are there any error logs? What debugging steps have you taken here?

Comment: `signup` and `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` work fine. I do see an account created when the form is submitted. The problem is with `history.push("/")`. For some reason, it doesn't redirect me to the home page after signing up like it should do, only the url on the search bar changes. Strangely enough, `history.push` works just fine when I remove the signup function.

Comment: I've copy/pasted much of your code into a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-dom-firebase-auth-history-push-changes-url-but-does-not-render-n-bhtqe3?file=/src/App.js), mocked the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` function, and cannot reproduce the navigation issue. Are you sure there are no errors or anything in your code preventing the create user function to work correctly then allow the navigation to occur? They are both rather independent of one another.

Comment: I copied/pasted and used your custom `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` function and everything worked just fine. The Firebase one didn't though. I even tested the login function and the same problem happened. There seems to be something happening behind the scenes that I am not aware of.

Comment: okay so after looking at my code, i realized the thing making `history.push("/")` fail was the line `setIsLoading(true)` in `AuthProvider`'s `useEffect`. I can't believe this has been driving me crazy for hours lol . Thanks for the help btw @DrewReese

Answer (score 0):

So, after testing and revising my code, I found out that the problem lies in `setIsLoading(true)` in `AuthProvider`'s `useEffect`. Remove that line and everything works like a charm. Hopefully this helps someone experiencing the same problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

Yes, I see now where an issue lies with using the `isLoading` state to conditionally render the entire app. After creating a new user it seems the `onAuthStateChanged` handler is invoked and current user is reloaded. When toggling the `isLoading` state true the `AuthContext`'s children are unmounted.

```
export function AuthProvider({ children }) {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState();
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  function signup(email, password) {
    return createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
  }

  const value = {
    currentUser,
    signup
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscriber = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      setIsLoading(true); // <-- setting true
      setCurrentUser(user);
      setIsLoading(false);
    });
      return unsubscriber;
  }, []);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
      {!isLoading && children} // <-- unmounts children
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

## Solution

A more practical solution is to add the `isLoading` state to the context value and create a protected route component that handles conditionally rendering null or a loading indicator, or the routed component or a redirect to log in.

Example:

```
export function AuthProvider({ children }) {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState();
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  function signup(email, password) {
    return createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscriber = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      setCurrentUser(user);
      setIsLoading(false);
    });

    return unsubscriber;
  }, []);

  const value = {
    currentUser,
    isLoading,
    signup
  }

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
      {children} // <-- keep children mounted!
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

...

```
const ProtectedRoute = props => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const { currentUser, isLoading } = useAuth();

  if (isLoading) {
    return null;
  }

  return currentUser
    ? <Route {...props} />
    : (
      <Redirect
        to={{
          pathname: "/login",
          state: { from: location } // <-- used to redirect back after auth
        }}
      />
    );
};
```

...

```
function App() {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <ProtectedRoute path="/somethingToProtect" component={<Private />} />
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
          <Route path="/" component={Home} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </AuthProvider>
  )
}
```